# printf("%d", x) alters value of %d when spaces are added to the formatted string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, formatting, format

Consider this very simple lines of code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int board[8][8];


board * initBoard(void)
{
    board * b = malloc(sizeof(board));
    if (!b) { return b; }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++){
            *b[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

void toggle(board * b, int x, int y)
{
    if (*b[x][y] == 1){
        *b[x][y] = 0;
        return;
    }
    *b[x][y] = 1;
}

void dumpBoard(board * b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++){
            printf("%d", *b[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    board * b = initBoard();
    if (!b) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    dumpBoard(b);
    toggle(b, 3, 5);
    toggle(b, 7, 7);
    printf("\n");
    dumpBoard(b);
}
```

In `main`, we initialize a board (8x8 array of ints) with all values to `0`. We print it with `dumpBoard`, then we toggle some of the values to `1` with `toggle`, and then we print it again. The output is the expected one; namely:

```c
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000100
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000001
```

However, in `dumpBoard`, if instead of  `printf("%d", *b[i][j]);` I make  `printf("%d   ", *b[i][j]);` (this is, if I add spaces to the formatted string to make the matrix look nicer when printed) I get this:

```c
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  540024864  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  540024864  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

For some reason, the matrix position `(2, 2)` has that very large value. No other change in the code was made. I find this to be very strange and potentially related to some memory issue - though why such issue would be triggered when adding spaces in the formatted string, I know not.

I am very new to C so please excuse if this is simple.

Comment: what is `board`?

Comment: Why are you doing `*b[i][j]` instead of `b[i][j]`? This implies that `b` is a triple star pointer?

Comment: @CraigEstey probably `board` is not what you think. It would not compile if it is an array. But As we do not know what it is then it is impossible to help

Comment: @Craig Estey  nailed it, imo.  The problem goes away when we stop de-refreencing b in the printf() statement.   https://godbolt.org/z/oqW95ePnW   -- I admit I'm making a huge assumption about the board typedef.

Comment: @0___________ that would maybe give a warning but I think it would compile anyway.

Comment: Please excuse my omission of the definition of `board`, I have added it to the beginning of the code.

Comment: @lafinur, I think you need `b[0][i][j]` or `(*b)[i][j]` as `*b[i][j]` is like `*(b[i][j])`.

Comment: @lafinur Consider moving the array into a `struct` with the array as a member of the `struct`.

Comment: Certainly a dupe.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Doing (*b)[i][j] works. Thank you for pointing this out. Why would it be benefitial to move the array into a struct?

Comment: Because you could pass a pointer to the struct around and not need to dereference the triple pointer to get to the 2d array. It would be a lot less messy and a lot less surprising to anyone else looking at the code.

Comment: When I compile the code with `gcc -fanalyzer` it seems that the allocation is too small, and running under Valgrind confirms it.  I think your typedef is actually giving you an array[8] of pointer-to-array[8] of int, rather than a 2d array.

Comment: @TobySpeight  `typedef int board[3][5]; printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(board), sizeof(int), sizeof(int *));` gives me `60 4 8`.  What do you get?

Comment: @chux, I get the same.  I confused myself thinking 8✕8=256; doh!  But it's still the case that `-fanalyzer` and Valgrind fail by overrunning the 256 bytes allocated, but when I switch to `typedef struct board
{
    int cells[8][8];
} board;` both of those run cleanly.  I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Oh, it's precedence of `*` vs `[]`, as you commented earlier.  I see.  Changing to use `(*b)[]` fixes them all.

Comment: @chux I saw this had 2 reopen votes in the review queue so I opened it and then closed it as a dupe. Feel free to edit the dupe target or add others, if you know any better ones.